# How do I stack many frequency tables in SAS

Tags: sas, frequency

I have a dataset of about 800 observations. I want to get the frequency of  14 variables.   I want to get the frequency of these variable by shape (an example). There are 3 different shapes.

An example of doing this one time would obviously be:
proc freq; tables color; by shape;run;

However, I do not want 42 frequency tables. I want one frequency table that has the list of 14 variables on the left side. The top heading will have shape1 shape2 shape3 with the frequencies of each variable underneath them.
 It would look like I transposed the data sets by percentage and then stacked them on top of each other.

I have several sets of combinations where I need to do this. I have about 5 different groups of variables and I need to make tables using 3 different by groups (necessitating about 15 tables). The first example I discussed is one example of such groups.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into proc tabulate. It's like proc freq on steroids.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/e0903d269d4a71316a4e

Comment: @Quentin- I have tried proc tabulate, but it does something I don't like with the missing data. If I have an observation with a missing response on one variable, I do not want it dropped from the table entirely. I still want the observation included in the other variables. However, the missing option includes the frequencies of the missing data. which I also don't want. Is there a way around this in proc tabulate?

Comment: @Reeza- thanks for the **gist**. It is almost exactly what I need, but I also need to account for by-groups. It would by nice to have the by group variable (for example:by age) in a column in the frequency table. I can make do with separate tables for each by group variable, though. For example, table 1 could have all of the variable frequencies for the 15 variables by shape1 and the second table would have all of the variable frequencies by shape 2 (etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `proc means` and `proc transpose`. I give you some example. You can add more categories.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class nway n; 
    class sex age;
    output out=class(drop=_freq_ _type_) n=freq;
run;

proc transpose data=class out=class(drop=_name_) prefix=AGE;
    by sex;
    var freq;
    id age;
run;

data class_sum;
    set class;

    array a(*) age:;
    age_sum = sum(of age:);

    do i = 1 to dim(a);
        a(i) = a(i) / age_sum;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Sozynski, I can see this as working. I do want the frequencies expressed as percentages. I can   use arrays to create a sum of Age11-Age16 and then divide each column by the sum. Do you have a more efficient way to express the #s as percentages?

Comment: Thanks Robert, this really helps!